# pip install PyGTK error

Tags: python, pip, gtk, installation

i type the following into the command prompt as administrator:

```
pip install PyGTK
```

and get the following error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyGTK <from versions:>
No matching distribution found for PyGTK
```

any thoughts of why this is happening, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PyGTK](https://pypi.org/project/PyGTK/#files) is only available for Python 2.6 on Windows.

For more fresh installation instructions see https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

Answer (score 0):

It's `pygtk`. Case sensitivity has caused the error probably. This has been deprecated for python3 though and has been replaced by `pygi`.