# Can't install PyGTK on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, pip, windows-10

I already have Python installed, aswell as PIP & PyObject v 1.0,
but trying to install PyGTK is throwing and error. Will add other relivant questions in a minute.
The given output error is listed below. I am using windows 10 & Hyper CMD from Github.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.508]
(c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Ryan>cd Desktop

C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop>cd Python

C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\Python>pip install PyGTK
Collecting PyGTK
  Using cached pygtk-2.24.0.tar.bz2 (2.4 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python38\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Ryan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-dvq3hehj\\pygtk\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Ryan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-dvq3hehj\\pygtk\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' 
egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-_fc9fnz2'
         cwd: C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dvq3hehj\pygtk\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    ERROR: Could not import dsextras module: Make sure you have installed pygobject.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\Python>pip install pyobject
Collecting pyobject
  Downloading pyobject-1.0.tar.gz (12 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pyobject, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pyobject
    Running setup.py install for pyobject ... done
Successfully installed pyobject-1.0

C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\Python>pip install pygtk
Collecting pygtk
  Using cached pygtk-2.24.0.tar.bz2 (2.4 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python38\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Ryan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qotfp_ry\\pygtk\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Ryan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qotfp_ry\\pygtk\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' 
egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-p2eqklxp'
         cwd: C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qotfp_ry\pygtk\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    ERROR: Could not import dsextras module: Make sure you have installed pygobject.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\Python>
```

Possibly related question ::>>
[Pip install unroll Python Setup PyEgg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/pip-install-unroll-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1)
[Pip Install PyGTK Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51485536/pip-install-pygtk-error)
[ReadTheDocs => PygObject](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)

If PyGTK is a python Package then why does it rely on such program as MSYS2 to be installed, and if this does need to be installed why is the terminal not mentioning this as an error or a necessary dependancy?

The given example pictures on the ReadTheDocs Website look like their installing it on a windows system from the 1970's so not sure how upto date that article is. Says Windows 7 and upwards.. I am running Windows 10 Home, Latest Updates...

Ps What are some good alternatives to PyGTK?
are there any that are better for GUI [PyGTK alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/pygtk/)
Not sure which ones in the list to look into has anyone used any of these?

The question that has been sugested as a duplicate is over 3 years old and MSYS2 still does not look like its is up to date or being actively maintained. Also I am using a different version of python.

Looking for a simple way to build GUI on windows, for basic task's and learning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [install pygtk for python 3.6.1 on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43529675/install-pygtk-for-python-3-6-1-on-windows-10)

Comment: @alex-rudenko Partially does, So It seems i've either got to use an older version of python & an outdated version of MSYS2, or find a different library/module for graphics.. Do you knowany updated alternatives?